# import of css from top level css is blocked

Tags: css, firefox, noscript

Inside a web page I have the following snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<base href="https://XXXXX /">
<title>Example</title>
<link href="Layout/standard.css" type="text/css" title="Example" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
```

The referenced page `standard.css` looks like this:

```
@import url( "standard2.css" );
@import url( "standard3.css" );
```

After upgrading the [noscript plugin](http://noscript.net) (version 2.4.3) within Firfefox ESR 10.0.4 the css pages `standard2.css` and `standard3.css` are not loaded anymore. With an earlier version of noscript everything worked as expected.

Why is noscript blocking this? Is there a known security problem importing a css from within another css? Or is it simply a bug in noscript?

---

**Update**: The problem is not the cascaded import. The problem is that I used a short URL (`https://hostname/...`). If I use a fully qualified URL (`https://hostname.mynet.com/...`) everything is working.

So it really looks like a bug in noscript 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

The NoScript [changelog](http://noscript.net/changelog) doesn't mention any changes to this, so it's probably a bug.